# How do I access a distinguished field in a BizTalk multipart message

Tags: biztalk

I have a multipart message with this schema  (edited for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://MyCompany/Schemas/Canonical/Property/1.0" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://MyCompany/Schemas/Canonical/Property/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Property">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:properties>
          <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='Property' and namespace-uri()='http://MyCompany/Schemas/Canonical/Property/1.0']/*[local-name()='UPRN' and namespace-uri()='']" />
        </b:properties>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Addresses">
          <xs:complexType />
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UPRN" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Given that the message name in an Orchestration is MyMessage, how would I access the value of the distinguished field 'UPRN' in a BizTalk Expression Editor.

When I try dot notation all I get from IntilliSense is MyMessage.Property

Comment: UPRN is defined as minOccurs 0, that could cause you issues.

Comment: Very odd.  I can reproduce the issue with the schema you supplied, but when I manually re-created the schema it works as expected.

Comment: And now I cannot reproduce anymore.  So must be something odd going on.  Try removing the Multi-Part Message Type and re-creating it.

Answer (score -1):

It's supposed to be:

MessageName.PartName.RootNode.ElememtName[...].FieldName

Comment: So, this answer is correct...downvote not correct, sorry :(

Comment: Actually, Rootnode is not in there.